# how to convert integer time to time object in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have following pandas dataframe

```
  code     time
  1        170000
  2        70000
  3        123000
  4        120000
```

My desired dataframe is following

```
  code     time       new_time 
  1        170000     17:00:00
  2        70000      07:00:00
  3        123000     00:30:00
  4        120000     00:00:00
```

I am doing following in python

```
data['new_time'] = [time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(x)) for x in data['time']]
data['new_time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['new_time']).dt.time
```

It's giving me some weird conversion. How can I do it?

Comment: Just to confirm: last two lines should not be `12:30` and `12:00` but rather `00:30` and `00:00`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `format` argument in `pd.to_datetime` (no need for the list comprehension or the `time` module):

```
data['new_time'] = pd.to_datetime(data.time, format='%H%M%S').dt.time

>>> data
   code    time  new_time
0     1  170000  17:00:00
1     2   70000  07:00:00
2     3  123000  12:30:00
3     4  120000  12:00:00
```

Comment: How would you differentiate between 12 pm and 12 am? Or is `12` in the hour always `00`?

Comment: its giving me `ValueError: time data 0 does not match format '%H%M%S' (match)` error

Comment: If they are integers, make them strings

Comment: There must be some times that don't match the format. You can also do `pd.to_datetime(data.time, format='%H%M%S', errors='coerce').dt.time`, which will return `NaN` in the rows where the format is not interpretable as a time

Comment: @sacul I have `0` in time column for which it should give `00:00:00`

Comment: I think that is why its giving me `ValueError: time data 0 does not match format '%H%M%S' (match)`

Comment: If that's you only edge case, then replace `0` with `000000`: `pd.to_datetime(data.time.replace(0,'000000'), format='%H%M%S', errors='coerce').dt.time`

Comment: Can also take a look at `zfill` ;)